# Swift, macOS, mac with 2 GPUs, matrix operations work on one GPU, not on the other

Tags: swift, macos, gpu, matrix-multiplication

I'm running macOS on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015), which has two GPUs in it, according to "About this Mac" in the Apple menu. One GPU is an AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2 GB, the other is an Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB -- the standard chips, I guess? They're the chips that were in there when I bought it, nothing I added myself.

I'm using the Swift MPS library for matrix computations; it works great on the Intel GPU, but when I select the Radeon, I only ever get back zeros from every operation, with no error reported. I've looked around for documentation on it, but I can't find anything. The only clue I have so far is that the Radeon reports "not integrated" (or at least, I think it does, based on the sample code at [Finding GPUs on macOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/gpu_selection_in_macos/finding_gpus_on_macos), which is about as useful as Apple's doc ever is, meaning *not very*). If I've read that page correctly, this is what my two GPUs are telling me.

`Device Intel Iris Pro Graphics; caps: headful, not discrete, integrated, not external`

`Device AMD Radeon R9 M370X; caps: headful, discrete, not integrated, not external`

I can't find any doc that would suggest what I'm doing wrong. I've been all over Apple's MPS documentation, to no avail. And as I say, the code works great on the Intel GPU, so I should think it would run on the Radeon too. I've run some downloadable diagnostic tools to check on the Radeon, but it doesn't show up in the menus of those tools. So I don't even know whether this is something I'm doing wrong in the code, or if the chip itself is broken.

Below is the code, which you can build as a console app by pasting into `main.swift`. Find the following line:

```
let device = MTLCopyAllDevices()[1]
```

I use `[0]` for the Intel, `[1]` for the Radeon, and you can see that the output is different, that is, all zeros for the Radeon. I suppose your mileage may vary depending on your machine. I welcome any input, cheers

```
import MetalPerformanceShaders

typealias MPSNumber = Float32

let MPSNumberSize = MemoryLayout<MPSNumber>.size
let MPSNumberTypeInGPU = MPSDataType.float32

class MPSNet {
    let commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer
    let commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue
    let device = MTLCopyAllDevices()[1]
    var neuronsInMatrix1: MPSMatrix?
    var neuronsInMatrix2: MPSMatrix?
    var neuronsOutMatrix: MPSMatrix?

    init() {
        guard let cq = device.makeCommandQueue() else { fatalError() }
        guard let cb = cq.makeCommandBuffer() else { fatalError() }

        commandQueue = cq
        commandBuffer = cb

        let cMatrices = 2
        let cRows = 1
        let cColumns = 3

        let sensoryInputs1: [MPSNumber] = [1, 2, 3]
        let sensoryInputs2: [MPSNumber] = [4, 5, 6]

        neuronsInMatrix1 = makeMatrix(device, sensoryInputs1)
        neuronsInMatrix2 = makeMatrix(device, sensoryInputs2)

        let rowStride = MPSMatrixDescriptor.rowBytes(fromColumns: cColumns, dataType: MPSNumberTypeInGPU)
        neuronsOutMatrix = makeMatrix(device, cRows, cColumnsOut: cColumns, rowStride: rowStride)

        let adder = MPSMatrixSum(
            device: device, count: cMatrices, rows: cRows, columns: cColumns, transpose: false
        )

        adder.encode(
            to: commandBuffer,
            sourceMatrices: [neuronsInMatrix1!, neuronsInMatrix2!],
            resultMatrix: neuronsOutMatrix!, scale: nil, offsetVector: nil,
            biasVector: nil, start: 0
        )

        commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler { _ in
            let motorOutputs = self.getComputeOutput(self.neuronsOutMatrix!)

            let discrete = !self.device.isLowPower && !self.device.isRemovable
            let caps = "\(self.device.isHeadless ? " headless" : " headful")" +
                       "\(discrete ? ", discrete" : ", not discrete")" +
                       "\(self.device.isLowPower ? ", integrated" : ", not integrated")" +
                       "\(self.device.isRemovable ? ", external" : ", not external")"

            print("Device \(self.device.name); caps:\(caps); motor outputs \(motorOutputs)")
        }
    }

    func compute() {
        commandBuffer.commit()
        commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
    }
}

extension MPSNet {
    func getComputeOutput(_ matrix: MPSMatrix) -> [Double] {
        let rc = matrix.data.contents()
        return stride(from: 0, to: matrix.columns * MPSNumberSize, by: MPSNumberSize).map {
            offset in

            let rr = rc.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: MPSNumber.self)

            return Double(rr)
        }
    }

    func loadMatrix(_ data: MTLBuffer, _ rawValues: [MPSNumber]) {
        let dContents = data.contents()

        zip(stride(from: 0, to: rawValues.count * MPSNumberSize, by: MPSNumberSize), rawValues).forEach { z in
            let (byteOffset, rawValue) = (z.0, MPSNumber(z.1))

            dContents.storeBytes(of: rawValue, toByteOffset: byteOffset, as: MPSNumber.self)
        }
    }

    func makeMatrix(_ device: MTLDevice, _ rawValues: [MPSNumber]) -> MPSMatrix {
        let rowStride = MPSMatrixDescriptor.rowBytes(
            fromColumns: rawValues.count, dataType: MPSNumberTypeInGPU
        )

        let descriptor = MPSMatrixDescriptor(
            dimensions: 1, columns: rawValues.count, rowBytes: rowStride,
            dataType: MPSNumberTypeInGPU
        )

        guard let inputBuffer = device.makeBuffer(
            length: descriptor.matrixBytes, options: MTLResourceOptions.storageModeManaged
        ) else { fatalError() }

        loadMatrix(inputBuffer, rawValues)

        return MPSMatrix(buffer: inputBuffer, descriptor: descriptor)
    }

    func makeMatrix(_ device: MTLDevice, _ cRowsOut: Int, cColumnsOut: Int, rowStride: Int) -> MPSMatrix {
        let matrixDescriptor = MPSMatrixDescriptor(
            dimensions: cRowsOut, columns: cColumnsOut,
            rowBytes: rowStride, dataType: MPSNumberTypeInGPU
        )

        return MPSMatrix(device: device, descriptor: matrixDescriptor)
    }
}

let net = MPSNet()
net.compute()
```

Comment: Question: On windows, you have to assign an application/program to run on a specific gpu when there is more than one available - or you can make everything run on one of them based on your power state (ie - plugged in or battery). From what I can tell on my mac - I can make the power state based choice. Maybe you can try that and tell me what happens  when you make everything run on AMD when plugged in and then we can check if an application based setting can be made (if you are interested in that)

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! I've learned a hundred times more than I knew before just by following up on your lead. I experimented with that power setting, and read some articles related to it, and now I'm starting to think the chip is broken. I'll keep you posted if you like, so we can put together an answer and you can get the points when I finally figure something out. Cheers

Comment: Ahh a broken chip? Too bad everything is so compact on the MacBook Pro. I usually can easily verify if the chip has gone bust or the chip seating has degraded due to overheating on most laptops I have had by pointing a heat gun at the gpu on the motherboard. If it work for the next 10 mins and fails - it’s the microballs that had melted and gotten displaced and displaced again. But before you head down this mad-scientist/broke-gamer route, ask someone with a similar working env to see if the code works on their end.

Comment: I guess the chip is ok; I downloaded some stuff from Apple, written in Objective-C, which I don't really know, but I've managed to compile it and see it using both GPUs just fine. I'll try to work on it some more today, to figure out the details. Cheers

Comment: Any luck with this? I need to add an eGPU to my mac and there are no drivers for my GPU for macOS. So I have to write one, just wanted to know if your objective-C approach worked out

Comment: Sorry, no luck at all. I've been poking at Apple's Objective-C example all this time. It works great, but I can't get it to work in my Swift translation

Comment: @SamThomas The problem is that I was using `MTLResourceOptions.storageModeManaged` instead of `MTLResourceOptions.storageModeShared`. I changed that, and everything works fine even without the call to `MPSMatrix.synchronize(on:)` as mentioned in one of the answers below. Best of luck to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the storage mode of your matrix buffers. You're using `MTLResourceOptions.storageModeManaged`, which tells Metal that you want to manage synchronization of the memory being shared between the CPU and GPU. As mentioned in another answer here, you must use `MPSMatrix.synchronize(on: MTLCommandBuffer)` after a GPU operation before you try to read the data with the CPU. But you must also synchronize in the other direction, ie, after CPU operations before you commit the command to the GPU, using `MTLBuffer.didModifyRange(_: Range)`.

Alternatively, you can use the shared storage mode, `MTLResourceOptions.storageModeShared`, which takes care of the synchronization for you.

See [Synchronizing a Managed Resource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/synchronizing_a_managed_resource) in the Apple doc for details.

Below is a working version of your example using the managed storage mode as you have. Notice the differences in function `MPSNet.compute()`. You can leave that stuff out and just change the storage mode when creating the `MTLBuffer`s for your matrices if your app is ok to use the shared storage mode.

```
import MetalPerformanceShaders

typealias MPSNumber = Float32

let MPSNumberSize = MemoryLayout<MPSNumber>.size
let MPSNumberTypeInGPU = MPSDataType.float32

class MPSNet {
    let commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer
    let commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue
    let device = MTLCopyAllDevices()[1]
    var neuronsInMatrix1: MPSMatrix?
    var neuronsInMatrix2: MPSMatrix?
    var neuronsOutMatrix: MPSMatrix?

    init() {
        guard let cq = device.makeCommandQueue() else { fatalError() }
        guard let cb = cq.makeCommandBuffer() else { fatalError() }

        commandQueue = cq
        commandBuffer = cb

        let cMatrices = 2
        let cRows = 1
        let cColumns = 3

        let sensoryInputs1: [MPSNumber] = [1, 2, 3]
        let sensoryInputs2: [MPSNumber] = [4, 5, 6]

        neuronsInMatrix1 = makeMatrix(device, sensoryInputs1)
        neuronsInMatrix2 = makeMatrix(device, sensoryInputs2)

        let rowStride = MPSMatrixDescriptor.rowBytes(fromColumns: cColumns, dataType: MPSNumberTypeInGPU)
        neuronsOutMatrix = makeMatrix(device, cRows, cColumnsOut: cColumns, rowStride: rowStride)

        let adder = MPSMatrixSum(
            device: device, count: cMatrices, rows: cRows, columns: cColumns, transpose: false
        )

        adder.encode(
            to: commandBuffer,
            sourceMatrices: [neuronsInMatrix1!, neuronsInMatrix2!],
            resultMatrix: neuronsOutMatrix!, scale: nil, offsetVector: nil,
            biasVector: nil, start: 0
        )

        commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler { _ in
            let motorOutputs = self.getComputeOutput(self.neuronsOutMatrix!)

            let discrete = !self.device.isLowPower && !self.device.isRemovable
            let caps = "\(self.device.isHeadless ? " headless" : " headful")" +
                       "\(discrete ? ", discrete" : ", not discrete")" +
                       "\(self.device.isLowPower ? ", integrated" : ", not integrated")" +
                       "\(self.device.isRemovable ? ", external" : ", not external")"

            print("Device \(self.device.name); caps:\(caps); motor outputs \(motorOutputs)")
        }
    }

    func compute() {
        for matrix in [neuronsInMatrix1!, neuronsInMatrix2!, neuronsOutMatrix!] {
            let matrixData = matrix.data
            matrixData.didModifyRange(0..<matrixData.length)

            matrix.synchronize(on: commandBuffer)
        }

        commandBuffer.commit()
    }
}

extension MPSNet {
    func getComputeOutput(_ matrix: MPSMatrix) -> [Double] {
        let rc = matrix.data.contents()
        return stride(from: 0, to: matrix.columns * MPSNumberSize, by: MPSNumberSize).map {
            offset in

            let rr = rc.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: MPSNumber.self)

            return Double(rr)
        }
    }

    func loadMatrix(_ data: MTLBuffer, _ rawValues: [MPSNumber]) {
        let dContents = data.contents()

        zip(stride(from: 0, to: rawValues.count * MPSNumberSize, by: MPSNumberSize), rawValues).forEach { z in
            let (byteOffset, rawValue) = (z.0, MPSNumber(z.1))

            dContents.storeBytes(of: rawValue, toByteOffset: byteOffset, as: MPSNumber.self)
        }
    }

    func makeMatrix(_ device: MTLDevice, _ rawValues: [MPSNumber]) -> MPSMatrix {
        let rowStride = MPSMatrixDescriptor.rowBytes(
            fromColumns: rawValues.count, dataType: MPSNumberTypeInGPU
        )

        let descriptor = MPSMatrixDescriptor(
            dimensions: 1, columns: rawValues.count, rowBytes: rowStride,
            dataType: MPSNumberTypeInGPU
        )

        guard let inputBuffer = device.makeBuffer(
            length: descriptor.matrixBytes, options: MTLResourceOptions.storageModeManaged
        ) else { fatalError() }

        loadMatrix(inputBuffer, rawValues)

        return MPSMatrix(buffer: inputBuffer, descriptor: descriptor)
    }

    func makeMatrix(_ device: MTLDevice, _ cRowsOut: Int, cColumnsOut: Int, rowStride: Int) -> MPSMatrix {
        let matrixDescriptor = MPSMatrixDescriptor(
            dimensions: cRowsOut, columns: cColumnsOut,
            rowBytes: rowStride, dataType: MPSNumberTypeInGPU
        )

        return MPSMatrix(device: device, descriptor: matrixDescriptor)
    }
}

let net = MPSNet()
net.compute()
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have failed to use -[MPSMatrix synchronizeOnCommandBuffer:]. On discrete devices, some explicit synchronization is required before the data will come back from the GPU.